# Is it possible to add a signature when sending mail using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been working with PHPMailer and it's working fine. Can I add a signature, like what Outlook has?

Comment: How are you sending mail? Your tags suggest your using jquery and ajax, php and asp.net....? What technology are you using? I don't know how you intend to use it, but could you not just concatenate it to the end of your message string?

Comment: a signiture is just text at the bootom of the message.

Answer (score 5):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_block#E-mail_and_Usenet
gives an overview about email signatures. As guys already mentioned, signature is just a part of the email body. The only restrictions are: "*it should be delimited from the body of the message by a single line consisting of exactly two hyphens, followed by a space, followed by the end of line (i.e., "-- \n")*".

Comment: Of course, different email clients may use different signatures, but my example from Wikipedia is one of the most common and oldest, so most of the clients will understand it.

Comment: sounds dated, all my sigs are html with pics, if the email is html no reason the sig cant be

Comment: Dagon, thanks for the comment. I hope at least the remaining part of the quote will help.

Answer (score 2):

If you've rapped the mailing procedure in a function, then have the function add your signature to the end of the body ($mail->MsgHTML).

As clarification...

```
$body = 'My message';
$body .= 'My signature';

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```